# Problems with signal 6

Tags: c

while I was programming on codewars, I encountered an error called signal 6.

The program works correctly on most unit tests, but takes error on one of them:
**Test Crashed
Caught unexpected signal: 6**

If you know what could be the cause of the error, I would be glad for your help. Thanks!

This is assignment conditions:

---

The aim of the kata is to decompose n! (factorial n) into its prime factors.

Examples:

n = 12; decomp(12) -> "2^10 * 3^5 * 5^2 * 7 * 11"
since 12! is divisible by 2 ten times, by 3 five times, by 5 two times and by 7 and 11 only once.

n = 22; decomp(22) -> "2^19 * 3^9 * 5^4 * 7^3 * 11^2 * 13 * 17 * 19"

n = 25; decomp(25) -> 2^22 * 3^10 * 5^6 * 7^3 * 11^2 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23
Prime numbers should be in increasing order. When the exponent of a prime is 1 don't put the exponent.

**Notes:
the function is decomp(n) and should return the decomposition of n! into its prime factors in increasing order of the primes, as a string.
factorial can be a very big number (4000! has 12674 digits, n can go from 300 to 4000).
In Fortran - as in any other language - the returned string is not permitted to contain any redundant trailing whitespace: you can use dynamically allocated character strings.**

---

And this is my solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *func(char* p, int num);

char *decomp(int n)
{
    int size = 100;
    int* p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    
    char* res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
    char* res2 = res;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(p + i) = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2, k = i; k > 1;)
        {
            if (k % j == 0)
            {
                while (j > size)
                {
                    size += 100;
                    p = (int*)realloc(p, size);
                }
                *(p + j) += 1;
                k /= j;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (*(p + i) != 0)
        {
            res = func(res, i);
            if (*(p + i) != 1)
            {
                *(res++) = '^';
                res = func(res, *(p + i));
            }
            *(res++) = ' ';
            *(res++) = '*';
            *(res++) = ' ';
        }
    }

    *(res - 3) = '\0';

    return res2;
}

//takes a pointer to memory and convert there integer to str
char *func(char* p, int num)
{
    int len = 0;

    for (int i = 1; num / i > 0; i *= 10)
        len++;

    char* p2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 4);

    while (num > 0)
    {
        *(p2++) = (num % 10) + '0';
        num /= 10;
    }
    p2--;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        *(p++) = *(p2--);
    }
    *p = '\0';

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: 6 is (probably) SIGABRT.  Sounds like your process ran too long and the environment killed it because it ran out of time.

Comment: If you wrote a program and submitted it to entity A which downgraded it, please ask entity A what was wrong with it.  Please don't ask us to guess.  If entity A won't tell you, that's a logistical problem between you and entity A.  It's *not* a C programming problem we can help with.

Comment: I notice you are getting memory errors when `decomp` is run with a number >= 237. That will also kill your program with SIGABRT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `realloc` statement. You have:

```
while (j > size)
{
    size += 100;
    p = (int*)realloc(p, size);
}
```

where it should be

```
while (j > size)
{
    size += 100;
    p = (int*)realloc(p, sizeof(int)*size);
}
```

since you are allocating an array if ints and `sizeof(int) > 1` you are not
allocating enough memory. This is causing you to write to memory you have
not allocate and with large enough arguments to `decomp` causing you to write
to illegal addresses.

This causes you program to be killed with `SIGABRT` which is usually signal 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot and thanks averyone who have writed!

Comment: Another good thing to note is you are leaking a lot of memory. `func` allocates every time it is call and that memory is never freed.

Comment: Thank you second time, I 've just changed it!

Answer (score 0):

signal 6 is `SIGABRT`, which is normally received as part of the call to `abort()` routine, which is also called by macros like `assert()`.  Have you been using `assert()`? in your code, or some library code makes use of it?  It's impossible to go further with the information you provide.